# Где найти компонент для ввода градуса, минуты, секунды?

Tags: java, android

Нужен компонент (на подобии DatePickerDialog) для выбора градусов, минут и секунд.
Есть ли такое или как это можно самому сделать.

Comment: Три обычных NumberPicker?

Comment: Хотелось бы в "одном флаконе" или пример готовый, чтобы не "изобретать велосипед".

Comment: Три обычных NumberPicker.

Answer (score 0):

[Документация по Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

В частности

> FORMAT_SECONDS Constant used to specify formatting of a latitude or
>   longitude in the form "DDD:MM:SS.SSSSS" where D indicates degrees, M
>   indicates minutes of arc, and S indicates seconds of arc (1 minute =
>   1/60th of a degree, 1 second = 1/3600th of a degree).

[`static double convert(String coordinate)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert(java.lang.String))

> Converts a String in one of
>   the formats described by FORMAT_DEGREES, FORMAT_MINUTES, or
>   FORMAT_SECONDS into a double.